# Avoiding concurrent structures by manually triggering memory barriers

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-barriers

#### Background

I have a class whose instances are used to collect and publish data (uses [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`HashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html)):

```
public class DataCollector {

    private final SetMultimap<String, String> valueSetsByLabel
            = HashMultimap.create();

    public void addLabelValue(String label, String value) {
        valueSetsByLabel.put(label, value);
    }

    public Set<String> getLabels() {
        return valueSetsByLabel.keySet();
    }

    public Set<String> getLabelValues(String label) {
        return valueSetsByLabel.get(label);
    }
}
```

Instances of this class will now be passed between threads, so I need to modify it for thread-safety. Since Guava's `Multimap` implementations aren't thread-safe, I used a `LoadingCache` that lazily creates concurrent hash sets instead (see the [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and [`MapMaker`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) javadocs for details):

```
public class ThreadSafeDataCollector {

    private final LoadingCache<String, Set<String>> valueSetsByLabel
            = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .concurrencyLevel(1)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, Set<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Set<String> load(String label) {
                    // make and return a concurrent hash set
                    final ConcurrentMap<String, Boolean> map = new MapMaker()
                            .concurrencyLevel(1)
                            .makeMap();
                    return Collections.newSetFromMap(map);
                }
            });

    public void addLabelValue(String label, String value) {
        valueSetsByLabel.getUnchecked(label).add(value);
    }

    public Set<String> getLabels() {
        return valueSetsByLabel.asMap().keySet();
    }

    public Set<String> getLabelValues(String label) {
        return valueSetsByLabel.getUnchecked(label);
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm setting the concurrency level for both the loading cache and nested concurrent hash sets to `1` (meaning they each only read from and write to one underlying table). This is because **I only expect one thread at a time to read from and write to these objects**.

(To quote the [`concurrencyLevel`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#concurrencyLevel%28int%29) javadoc, "A value of one permits only one thread to modify the map at a time, but since read operations can proceed concurrently, this still yields higher concurrency than full synchronization.")

#### Problem

Because I can assume there will only be a single reader/writer at a time, I feel that using many concurrent hash maps per object is heavy-handed. Such structures are meant to handle concurrent reads and writes, and guarantee atomicity of concurrent writes. But in my case atomicity is unimportant - I only need to make sure each thread sees the last thread's changes.

In my search for a more optimal solution I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2388984/697449) by [erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474/erickson), which says:

> *Any* data that is shared between thread needs a "memory barrier" to ensure its visibility.
>
> [...]
>
> Changes to any member that is declared `volatile` are visible to all
>   threads. In effect, the write is "flushed" from any cache to main
>   memory, where it can be seen by any thread that accesses main memory.
>
> Now it gets a bit trickier. Any writes made by a thread *before* that
>   thread writes to a volatile variable are also flushed. Likewise, when
>   a thread reads a volatile variable, its cache is cleared, and
>   subsequent reads may repopulate it from main memory.
>
> [...]
>
> One way to make this work is to have the thread that is populating
>   your shared data structure assign the result to a `volatile` variable. [...]
>   When other threads access that variable, not only are they guaranteed
>   to get the most recent value for that variable, but also any changes
>   made to the data structure by the thread before it assigned the value
>   to the variable.

(See [this InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) for a further explanation of memory barriers.)

The problem erickson is addressing is slightly different in that the data structure in question is fully populated and then assigned to a variable that he suggests be made `volatile`, whereas my structures are assigned to `final` variables and gradually populated across multiple threads. But his answer suggests I could use a `volatile` dummy variable to manually trigger memory barriers:

```
public class ThreadVisibleDataCollector {

    private final SetMultimap<String, String> valueSetsByLabel
            = HashMultimap.create();

    private volatile boolean dummy;

    private void readMainMemory() {
        if (dummy) { }
    }

    private void writeMainMemory() {
        dummy = false;
    }

    public void addLabelValue(String label, String value) {
        readMainMemory();
        valueSetsByLabel.put(label, value);
        writeMainMemory();
    }

    public Set<String> getLabels() {
        readMainMemory();
        return valueSetsByLabel.keySet();
    }

    public Set<String> getLabelValues(String label) {
        readMainMemory();
        return valueSetsByLabel.get(label);
    }
}
```

<sub>Theoretically, I could take this a step further and leave it to the calling code to trigger memory barriers, in order to avoid unnecessary volatile reads and writes between calls on the same thread (potentially by using `Unsafe.loadFence` and `Unsafe.storeFence`, which were added in Java 8). But that seems too extreme and hard to maintain.</sub>

#### Question

Have I drawn the correct conclusions from my reading of erickson's answer (and the JMM) and implemented `ThreadVisibleDataCollector` correctly? I wasn't able to find examples of using a `volatile` dummy variable to trigger memory barriers, so I want to verify that this code will behave as expected across architectures.

Comment: It seems `ThreadVisibleDataCollector` would be dumping/reading entire data to memory, rather than just the label-values that are being accessed.

Comment: @S.D. Wouldn't this also be the case with concurrent hash maps? They use explicit locking, but `Lock` guarantees the same memory synchronization.

Comment: True. What I was wondering about was if `volatile` could be used for each { String label, Set<String> values } object. So, when you accessed a "label", then only that "label" and its set of "values" be synced with main memory, and not all other labels. This could be true with locking as well, i.e. more granular, "label" level locking.

Comment: @S.D. Interesting, that reminds me of Guava's [`Striped`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html). I'll consider whether it could be used, though in my particular use case most labels are written by a single thread, and all labels are read by another single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do is called **“Premature Optimization”**. You don’t have a real performance problem but try to make your entire program very complicated and possibly error prone, without any gain.

The reason why you will never experience any (notable) gain lies in the way how a lock works. You can learn a lot of it by studying the [documentation of the class `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html).

A `Lock` is formed around a simple `int` value with `volatile` semantics and atomic updates. In the simplest form, i.e. without contention, locking and unlocking consist of a single atomic update of this `int` variable. Since you claim that you can be sure that there will be only one thread accessing the data at a given time, there will be no contention and the lock state update has similar performance characteristics compared to your `volatile boolean` attempts but with the difference that the `Lock` code works reliable and is heavily tested.

The `ConcurrentMap` approach goes a step further and allows a lock-free read that has the potential to be even more efficient than your `volatile` read (depending on the actual implementation).

So you are creating a potentially *slower* and possibly *error prone* program just because you “feel that using many concurrent hash maps per object is heavy-handed”. The only answer can be: don’t feel. Measure. Or just leave it as is as long as there is no real performance problem.

Comment: You're right that I should have looked into the implementation of e.g. `ReentrantLock` before generalizing. Another gain that I had in mind was that my actual code is more complicated, and also uses a Guava `Table` - augmenting for thread safety means replacing it with two concurrent hash maps, in order to expose both cell and row views, and complicates the logic. But your arguments outweigh this excuse, especially about concurrent hash maps and locking being heavily tested.

Answer (score 1):

Some value is written to volatile variable *happens-before* **this** value can be read from it. As a consequence, the visibility guarantees you want will be achieved by reading/writing it, so the answer is **yes, this solves visibility issues**.

Besides the problems mentioned by *Darren Gilroy* in his answer, I'd like to remember that in Java 8 there are explicit memory barrier instructions in `Unsafe` class:

```
/**
 * Ensures lack of reordering of loads before the fence
 * with loads or stores after the fence.
 */
void loadFence();

/**
 * Ensures lack of reordering of stores before the fence
 * with loads or stores after the fence.
 */
void storeFence();

/**
 * Ensures lack of reordering of loads or stores before the fence
 * with loads or stores after the fence.
 */
void fullFence();
```

Although `Unsafe` is not a public API, I still recommend to at least consider using it, if you're using Java 8.

One more solution is coming to my mind. You have set your `concurrencyLevel` to `1` which means that only one thread at a time can do **anything** with a collection. IMO standard Java `synchronized` or `ReentrantLock` (for the cases of high contention) will also fit for your task and *do* provide visibility guarantees. Although, if you want *one writer, many readers* access pattern, consider using `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did make a mention of `loadFence` and `storeFence` in the subscript. I think it would be too much for the callers of the data collector to worry about when to trigger a barrier. Also see the `concurrencyLevel` javadoc quote in the question for why a concurrent hash map with concurrency level 1 is still preferable to full synchronization or manual locking.

Comment: @PaulBellora I'd call question about hard/easy to maintain volatile- or `fence()`-based code totally subjective thus makes no sense to argue. Regadring synchronization - that's true, I changed my suggestion to `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's still not particularly safe, b/c it depends a lot of the underlying implementation of the HashMultimap.

You might take a look at the following blog post for a discussion: http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

For this type of thing, a common pattern is to load a "most recent version" into a volatile variable and have your readers read immutable versions through that.  This is how `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is implemented.

Something like ...

```
class Collector {
   private volatile HashMultimap values = HashMultimap.create();

   public add(String k, String v) {
      HashMultimap t = HashMultimap.create(values);
      t.put(k,v);
      this.values = t;  // this invokes a memory barrier
   }

   public Set<String> get(String k) {
     values.get(k); // this volatile read is memory barrier
   }
}
```

However, both your and my solution still have a bit of a problem -- we are both returning *mutable views* on the underlying data structure.  I might change the `HashMultimap` to an `ImmutableMultimap` to fix the mutability issue.  Beware also that callers retain a reference to the full internal map (not just the returned Set) as a side effect of things being a view.

Creating a new copy can seem somewhat wasteful, but I suspect that if you have only one thread writing, then you have an understanding of the rate of change and can decide if that's reasonable or not.  For example, f you wanted to return `Set<String>` instances which update dynamically as things change then the solution based on map maker doesn't seem heavy handed.

Comment: It's not clear to me why it's "not particularly safe". Remember, I can assume only one thread reads/writes at a time, so triggering the memory barriers should be enough. Make sure to read erickson's quote - all writes to the hash multimap should be flushed by `writeMainMemory`. Or if I'm missing something please clarify.

Comment: I think the point of the linked blog is that the reader threads assume a stable structure as they read. In this case, you have a HashMap reader which is spun into an infinite loop because it sees the partially-changed structure.

-- Note: HashMap.put() underlies HashBasedTable.put() --

The memory barrier will assure that all of the writes done by the writing thread are seen by the reading thread (I think you’re on point here), but it does not assure that the reading threads see *only* what has been explicitly published.

Comment: It can still see the write in progress, and if it can see it in progress it can see the map in an unstable state.

Even if you only have one threading writing to a HashMap, if that thread is writing at the same time as a read, the reading thread can see partial data.

IOW, you need some way to preserve atomicity in addition to visibility.